# piezoelectric in quartz

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, second-quantization, piezoelectric

Does any one know if it is possible to find the relation between the ac current frequency applied to a piezoelectric and the change in the crystal lattice due to this current BY USE OF HAMILTONIAN (in second quantization form) OF THE PIEZOELECTRIC INTERACTION in Quartz(or any other piezoelectric)?!

Comment: See Many-Particle Physics
 By Gerald D. Mahan pgs 10-30

Comment: John M, I have read the same book and now i want to know how tp use it for calculating the relation between applied voltage and lattice oscillations??!! can you help more please?!